Reactive API needs to call parallel downstream APIs and await responses
I have a number of devices (currently eight, but could be more in the future) with a simple blocking HTTP REST api. One makes a GET call to give a value, the API responds with success or fail, but always a 200. There's another GET to find the current setting. So, a typical sequence would be:
http://\<some address\>/devicename/set/10
http://\<some address\>/devicename/get
I have a Spring Boot reactive API to call these downstream APIs in parallel that currently uses Mono.zip(). I only have the set() coded. When I call the reactive API, it works in that it makes all of the set() calls, and sends back a response to the reactive API caller showing the results.
The problem I have is: I need to programmatically await the results of all of the set() calls, do the get() calls, awaiting those responses, then optionally do more rounds of set() -> get() until the values all are either in compliance or the retries are exhausted.
I've tried a number of variations:

block() - errors at runtime with block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3
CountDownLatch inside a subscribe() - never completes and doesn't decrement the latch
subscribe() (several variations) - still doesn't await all of the responses.

I feel like there's something trivial I'm missing. Clearly, somewhere in the reactive API, the waiting is happening, because it always returns to the caller with all of the completed set() responses. Often, this will take 30 to 40 seconds for all to complete, which is expected and OK.
I need to be able to do that in the user code, and initiate the other calls as mentioned. I hit the reactive API with a browser, and honestly, even if the browser call times out, that's OK, as long as the work gets done. I do need to retain the parallel calls to the downstream in all cases, as each device can be doing the work at the same time.

So why use reactive? Write code to use an ExecutorService in a try-with-resources for all the set calls. Then do the same for the get calls. Check the returned Future objects for results. If any unset remains, repeat. So much simpler.

It's not related to the question at all, but if you change a value with a GET call, please don't call it REST. GET should not change the state of an object on the server. (See also MDN for the GET method of HTTP)

And related to your question: what will happen, when another client sends a GET request to get the value while you still process the GET request to set the value on the device?

I didn't design/write and don't control the downstream API, I only go with what I have. I'm aware that the GET should be PUT/PATCH, something, but it's what I have to work with. As to why I did reactive, it's what we're doing at my day job so I know enough to be dangerous. As to multiple calls, the downstream server will just block until the first call completes, then work the second call.

Not sure how to handle this from a etiquette standpoint, but upon reflection, I decided to take @BasilBourque advice and go with ExecutorService. It's working great!

Reactive unneeded
Reactive programming was a transitional technology created to maximize the performance of multithreaded workloads. Unfortunately, reactive programming is confusing, difficult to reason about, and nearly impossible to debug.
With the creation of virtual threads in Project Loom for Java, the need for reactive largely evaporates. See Do Java 21 virtual threads address the main reason to switch to reactive single-thread frameworks?, and video with Brian Goetz.
With virtual threads you get the high-performance of reactive, but also the simplicity of straightforward code, plus you can leverage all the debugging and thread-tracking features of our existing tools.
Your app scenario
In your case you seem to have a bunch of "Setter" tasks that you want to run concurrently. After all those tasks finish, you want to run a bunch of "Getter" tasks that verify the results of all that setting. So apparently you have a situation where those "Setter" tasks may fail or their work may be undone by some other unspecified process.
Executor service
To concurrently execute a bunch of tasks, use an ExecutorService in Java 5 and later.
If those tasks involve blocking, such as file I/O, database access, logging, socket connections, Web Services calls, etc., use an ExecutorService implementation backed by virtual threads in Java 21 and later.
Try-With-Resources syntax
With Java 19 and later, an ExecutorService object is AutoCloseable. This means you can use the convenient try-with-resources syntax to automatically close an ExecutorService after its submitted tasks are done.
So in your case, you use an ExecutorService in a try-with-resources to run your first group of tasks. Then
Example app
Here is some example code to demonstrate.
First a simple Device class with a mutable field to be altered by our Setter tasks and retrieved by our Getter tasks.
package work.basil.example.devices;

import java.util.UUID;

public class Device
{
    final UUID id;
    boolean setting;  // Mutable.

    public Device ( final UUID aDeviceId , final boolean aSetting )
    {
        this.id = aDeviceId;
        this.setting = aSetting;
    }
}

And a Polling class to:

Run a bunch of Setter tasks
Run a bunch of Getter tasks, after the Setter tasks are done.
Verify if all the results are as we expect/hope.

Notice that our Getter tasks tell a lie. They randomly return false rather than true. We do this as a simple way to simulate your apparent scenario where the settings either fail or get reversed mysteriously.
When submitting a task to an ExecutorService, we get back a Future object. Use the futures as a handle to the submitted task, to track its success/failure, and to retrieve its result (if a Callable rather than a Runnable task).
package work.basil.example.devices;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Polling
{    // Fields
    final private Collection < Device > devices;

    // Constructor
    public Polling ( final Collection < Device > devices )
    {
        this.devices = devices;
        System.out.println ( "devices = " + devices );

        // Run Setting tasks
        try
                (
                        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
                )
        {
            // Make a Setter task for each device. Submit task to executor service.
            devices.stream ( ).map ( Setter :: new ).forEach ( executorService :: submit );
        }
        // At this point the flow-of-control stops until all submitted tasks are done.

        // Run Getting tasks.
        List < Future < Boolean > > futures = new ArrayList <> ( );
        try
                (
                        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ( ) ;
                )
        {
            // Make a Setter task for each device. Submit task to executor service.
            for ( Device device : devices )
            {
                futures.add ( executorService.submit ( new Getter ( device ) ) );
            }
        }
        // At this point the flow-of-control stops until all submitted tasks are done.

        long countDevicesNotSetToTrue = futures.stream ( ).filter ( future -> !future.resultNow ( ) ).count ( );
        if ( countDevicesNotSetToTrue > 0 )
        {
            System.out.println ("Oops, not all set. Try again." );
        }
    }
}

// Getter task
class Getter implements Callable < Boolean >
{
    private final Device device;

    public Getter ( final Device aDevice ) { this.device = aDevice; }

    @Override
    public Boolean call ( )
    {
        // Sleep to simulate some blocking work, such as network calls, logging, database access, file I/O, etc.
        try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofSeconds ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 7 ) ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }

        boolean val = this.device.setting;
        System.out.println ( "Getting " + val + " for " + this.device.id );
        return val;
    }
}

// Setter task
class Setter implements Runnable
{
    private final Device device;

    public Setter ( final Device device ) { this.device = device; }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        // Sleep to simulate some blocking work, such as network calls, logging, database access, file I/O, etc.
        try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofSeconds ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 7 ) ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }

        // Set the setting, but not truthfully. Simulate the situation implied in the Question where the setting either fails or is later flipped.
        this.device.setting = ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextBoolean ( ); // Simulate the situation where setting may fail or may be changed later.
        System.out.println ( "Setting device value now for: " + this.device.id + ". Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: " + this.device.setting );
    }
}

Lastly we have an App class to make this go. We instantiate several Device objects which we submit to a Polling object.
package work.basil.example.devices;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println ("Hello World! "+ Instant.now() );
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( ) {
        Polling polling = new Polling (
                List.of (
                        new Device ( UUID.fromString ( "b60f3152-f425-4f50-b82e-28cc66acd650" ) , true ) ,
                        new Device ( UUID.fromString ( "a024571b-fc33-4026-b1ec-271f38f15e3f" ) , true ) ,
                        new Device ( UUID.fromString ( "2dd8f151-5351-4c14-a283-a5a40908009e" ) , true ) ,
                        new Device ( UUID.fromString ( "73a3dcfb-088d-4361-bebc-ab627f72589a" ) , true ) ,
                        new Device ( UUID.fromString ( "4d3cb1f3-9203-4034-b4de-ef84e6465dac" ) , true ) ,
                        new Device ( UUID.fromString ( "8a3b3cca-f9bf-47ed-8814-9074f0b346c7" ) , true ) ,
                        new Device ( UUID.fromString ( "b1c169fc-be87-4732-a0e9-bcb427715625" ) , true )
                )
        );
    }
}

When run:
Setting device value now for: a024571b-fc33-4026-b1ec-271f38f15e3f. Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: true
Setting device value now for: b1c169fc-be87-4732-a0e9-bcb427715625. Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: true
Setting device value now for: b60f3152-f425-4f50-b82e-28cc66acd650. Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: true
Setting device value now for: 4d3cb1f3-9203-4034-b4de-ef84e6465dac. Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: true
Setting device value now for: 8a3b3cca-f9bf-47ed-8814-9074f0b346c7. Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: true
Setting device value now for: 2dd8f151-5351-4c14-a283-a5a40908009e. Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: true
Setting device value now for: 73a3dcfb-088d-4361-bebc-ab627f72589a. Tried to set to `true`` but actually set to: false
Getting true for b1c169fc-be87-4732-a0e9-bcb427715625
Getting true for a024571b-fc33-4026-b1ec-271f38f15e3f
Getting true for 4d3cb1f3-9203-4034-b4de-ef84e6465dac
Getting true for 2dd8f151-5351-4c14-a283-a5a40908009e
Getting true for 8a3b3cca-f9bf-47ed-8814-9074f0b346c7
Getting false for 73a3dcfb-088d-4361-bebc-ab627f72589a
Getting true for b60f3152-f425-4f50-b82e-28cc66acd650
Oops, not all set. Try again.

